# Magento undefined variable: isCustomerLogged error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, customer, log

I'm getting this error in my logs, how can I solve this? Here is error and the file it relates to. This is line 15:

```
<?php if (!$isCustomerLogged): ?>
```

> ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: isCustomerLogged  in
> /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/detailedreview/wrapper.phtml
> on line 15

```
<?php if (!$isCustomerLogged): ?>
    <div class="login-dialog-block" style="display: none;">
        <div class="login-dialog-container">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_login');?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_register');?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `if (!$isCustomerLogged):` with below code

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php $customerIsLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn(); ?> //return if customer is logged in

<?php if (!$customerIsLoggedIn): ?> //here we hide the code bellow if customer is not logged in
    <div class="login-dialog-block" style="display: none;">
        <div class="login-dialog-container">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_login');?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_register');?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: It is @Prince again :D Yes it worked perfectly, accepted the users above answer as he was faster. Can you tell me why it suddenly started giving me this error? It was working fine until now.

Comment: No problem :) about your variable i don't know what you have in your code but maybe you have some conflict in this variable or some error

Comment: Hymmm... Okey I'll see how it all behaves now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem in Magento like undefined variables in all pages. 
Go to Index.php search below code & replaced.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
   Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
   Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
}